# Making a checkers board in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a 2D array that is 8x8 for a checkers game in python. How would I go about doing this?
Here is my current code:

```
class Board():    
    board = [[]]

    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def __repr__(self):
        print(self.board)

    def setup(self):
        for y in range(self.height):
            for x in range(self.width):
                self.board[y].append(0)

board = Board(8,8)
board.setup()
print(board.board)
```

Comment: Note: `__repr__` should not print anything but return a string representing the object.

Comment: Not sure what your requirements are, but it's probably easier to make something like an 8x8 array of booleans in numpy.

Comment: not to mention that if you create multiple boards they will all share the same data since `self.board` is a class attribute.

Answer (score 3):

```
board = [[0]*8 for i in range(8)] # This makes you 8x8 list
>>>[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

def setup(self):
    board = [[0]*self.height for i in range(self.width)]
```

You only change 8's with your instance attributes(self.heigth,self.width)

Answer (score 0):

At the point where your code does

```
self.board[y].append(0)
```

`self.board` has only one element, so for `y>0` this will fail. You need to make `self.board` contain not *one* empty list but `self.height` empty lists for this to work.

I am not going into more detail because, as one commenter has mentioned, this sounds a lot like homework and in such cases it's best for everyone not to fill in all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Nested lists can sometimes be difficult to work with. If you don't absolutely *need* a 2D list, I recommend using a dict. Creating a 2D array with a dict is easy. You can use a tuple of (row,column) as the index.

For example:

```
board = {}
for row in range(8):
    for column in range(8):
        board[(row, column)] = 0
```